# Cloning an OS disk onto a smaller disk

Tags: windows-server-2003, data-migration, cloning

I have a Windows 2003 server installed on a 2TB hard disk that I am trying to move to a 120GB SSD disk.

Usually for disk copying I use this 2-slot disk dock gadget where you insert the 2 disks in slot A and B, press a button and it makes an exact copy - sector by sector, simple and works great.

However this time I have a big disk (2TB) to move to a small disk (120GB). The data on it is 20GB so it should fit. But I had no luck with the approaches so far:

Robocopy G: H: /copyall /mir

is one thing I tried

Also tried to use Acronis TrueImage , Clone Disk Utility..

After the copying, the machine boots from the destination disk, gives me a login screen, but when I login it says "Some drivers failed see event log for details" and sends me right back to the login screen. It boots fine from the source disk.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I checked with msinfo32 that sector size on both disks is set to 512 bytes, and I am not sure if the "System Volume Information" folder should be copied or not.

*Endnote: I tried Automated System Recovery from Windows 2003 Server DVD, and it asked me to Insert a bootable floppy! Seriously Microsoft, a floppy? What is this, 1991? I have a spare floppy drive lying around, but there is no port on the motherboard to attach it to!*

Answer (score 0):

Acronis Clone Disk worked for me with some options settings, set the move method to Manual and then we get the option to "Change Disk Layout" and control how the unused space from the bigger disk will be shrunk when moving to smaller disk.. The destination disk is fine and bootable now!